# Does WSO2 Stream Processor Support Multi Tenancy?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm using WSO2 Stream Processor dashboard functionality to show API Manager analytics. However, I have different tenants that have different APIs. Is it possible to customize dashboard for different tenants? WSO2 API Manager Analytics solutions supports multi tenancy, is there a similar func. in Stream Processor?

Answer (score 0):

Follow this documentation and you will get a clear idea on your doubts.

https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/streaming-integrator/guides/use-cases/